# SQL: Linking Multiple Rows in Table Based on Data Chain in Select

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I'm trying to create a select statement which will return all linked rows based on a "LINK_SEQUENCE" column. The column however, only links two rows together. A simple query to combine the two makes perfect sense to me. However, in the case that three or more links in the "chain" are present, I want to make sure that all codes are returned.

[image: Table Data]

How would I go about returning something similar to this when only handing the query one of the codes involved? EX: 3245.

[image: Output Query]

Not sure if it much matters in this situation, but this is for an Oracle database. Thank you all very much!

Source data from SQL Fiddle:

```
ID  CODE    LINK_SEQUENCE   NAME
1   3267    1               Potato
2   3245    1               Potato
3   3245    2               Potato
4   3975    2               Potato
5   3975    3               Potato
6   5478    3               Potato
7   2368    4               Apricot
8   4748    4               Apricot
9   8957    (null)          Carrot
```

Comment: See if I get it right: given a "code", e.g. 3245, you want to select all rows that have the same `LINK_SEQUENCE` this code has?

Comment: I also want to get other codes in that chain... Note that with the table, IDs 1, 2, 3, and 4 should return when you input Code 3167, 3245, or 3975.

Comment: It's possible to have 1 or more link sequences involved in the chain...

Comment: Added **your** data from [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fca05/3).

Comment: What is your **version** of `Oracle`?

Comment: Can we have more than 2 records for **the same** sequence number? If so, how we find out the next code for our chain?

Comment: Updated my answer with the a new code. Please test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM LinkedTable lt
WHERE ft.link_sequence IN 
   ( SELECT link_sequence FROM LinkedTable WHERE code = 3245 AND link_sequence IS NOT NULL ) 
ORDER BY ft.ID;
```

See my [**SQL Fiddle DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fd1a3/1).

**SECOND ATTEMPT:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM LinkedTable
START WITH code = 3245
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
           PRIOR code = code  AND PRIOR link_sequence+1 = link_sequence OR
           PRIOR code <> code AND PRIOR link_sequence =   link_sequence
ORDER BY link_sequence, code
;
```

Updated [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fca05/20) with this code.  **Please try to break it.**

Based on your data (starting with `3245`) it gives the following chain:

```
ID  CODE    LINK_SEQUENCE   NAME
2   3245    1              Potato
1   3267    1              Potato
3   3245    2              Potato
4   3975    2              Potato
5   3975    3              Potato
6   5478    3              Potato
```

Comment: I also want to get other codes in that chain... Note that with the table, IDs 1, 2, 3, and 4 should return when you input Code 3167, 3245, or 3975.

Comment: Have you looked at my `SQL Fiddle` (it seems to be down now)? You can change data there and see how the script works. It's programmed to use as many sequences as there are in your table.  Play with it and let me know if you find any problems.

Comment: SQL Fiddle has been down all morning. I will go ahead and do that when I see that it is up. Thank you.

Comment: Here is an example where it doesn't work: [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fca05/3). In this example, entering the following codes should return the same list: 5478, 3975, 3245 and 3267.

Comment: I do not see why.  `5478` is assigned `3`.  I show all rows with `3`. Do not see anything wrong.  May be you need to clarify your task?

Comment: What I have is a table containing product information change history. In this table, the product information is entered before the change occurs. When a simple change (EX: description) is made, one simple entry is created. When the product's code changes, two entries are created. One from before and one from after the code change. The link_sequence is the only reference to this. What I am looking to do is to have a query which will return all of the history including past codes that may be involved. Two or three changes may have been made to a product's code during it's lifespan.

Comment: This is a different task than what was described before. Or at least, the way I understood it.  Could you please do step-by-step based on your Fiddle?  I can post it into your question if you do not know how to do it.  I mean, please explain why `5478, 3975, 3245 and 3267` should be returned.

Comment: The reason that all should be returned is that the product is one in the same. The code just happened to change over time from one to another. The history should be returned by this SQL. This history should show all product activity from it's inception. The product began with code 3267 and over time has evolved into product 5478.

Comment: How **exactly** is this *evolution* reflected i the table?  How `3267` (seq. `1`) is tied to `5478` (seq. `3`)?

Comment: 3267 is tied to 3245 by link_sequence 1, 3245 is tied to 3975 by link_sequence 2, and 3975 is tied to 5478 by link_sequence 3

Comment: Two more questions: (**1**) Does `NAME` play any roll at all? (**2**) If `LINK_SEQUENCE` is `NULL`, we just completely ignore such rows, right?

Comment: Name does not play a role at all. If the LINK_SEQUENCE is NULL, we still want it to return. It just doesn't happen to have a link to other records. Thank you very much for your patience.

Comment: You're welcome. Please test **thoroughly**. I had to put `NOCYCLE` clause in my code, since Oracle was complaining of circular references. By doing it I might just masked some programming logic problem.